# Up-to-date pre-condition testing?

Tags: php, post, null, php-7

I am testing for a given post request field on a script that can be called either from the command line, or over HTTP as a GET or POST request. As such, `$_POST` can be undefined. Is there a simple way of rewriting this statement?

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == "login"):
```

I could suppress errors with the `@`-operator — is that bad practice?

```
if (@$_POST['function'] == "login"):
```

I could use PHP 7.0's null coalesce operator, but that introduces a useless literal purely designed to throw a `false`:

```
if (($_POST['function'] ?? null) == "login"):
```

Comment: Probably not too popular of an opinion, but I think this is one case where using error suppression is justified. Implications when that index doesn't exist are obvious.

Comment: Variations of this question get asked now and then. I always recommend to stop caring, write a custom wrapper function and just use `if (get_input('function') == 'login')`.

Comment: @DanielSloof No need just use `php_sapi_name()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly but that introduces another test for the `if` statement. Also, you have marked this as duplicate: can you provide a link to where this has been asked before?

Comment: The link is at the top of your question in the yellow box

Comment: _but that introduces another test for the if statement_ Yes but one that provides an easy way of deciding where the script is running.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is not a duplicate of "What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, you don't need both `isset()` tests:

```php
if (isset($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == "login"):
```

Will work properly if `$_POST` is not set. For example:

```
php > var_dump(isset($notset[123][456]));
bool(false)
php >
```

I would also consider your usage of the null-coalesce operator to be proper and clean.

```
if (($_POST['function'] ?? null) == "login"):
```

This looks great to me.

You could also abstract this logic away behind some type of wrapper function:

```
function getFunction()
{
    return ($_POST['function'] ?? null);
}
```

Or, for older PHP:

```
function getFunction()
{
    return isset($_POST['function']) ? $_POST['function'] : null);
}
```